Why does my lock-free stack implementation fail on Windows and older Linux systems?
I'm working on a lock-free stack implementation using C++ and CAS (compare_exchange_strong/compare_exchange_weak). The implementation seems to work fine on modern Linux systems but fails on Windows and some older versions of Linux. Below is the complete code for testing multi-producer, multi-consumer thread safety:
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class LockFreeStack {
public:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node(const T& value) : data(value), next(nullptr) {}
    };

    LockFreeStack() : head(nullptr) {}
    ~LockFreeStack() {
        while (pop());
    }

    bool empty() {
        return head == nullptr;
    }

    void push(const T& value) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(value);
        auto q = head.load(memory_order_relaxed);

        do {
            new_node->next = q;
        } while (!head.compare_exchange_strong(q, new_node)); // Neither compare_exchange_strong nor compare_exchange_weak can guarantee thread safety.
    }

    Node* pop() {
        auto q = head.load(memory_order_acquire);
        while (q && !head.compare_exchange_strong(q, q->next)) {}
        return q;
    }

private:
    atomic<Node*> head;
};

int RollDice() {
    return rand() % 500 + 1;
}

void test_lock_free_stack() {
    LockFreeStack<int> stack;

    const int num_producers = 15;
    const int num_consumers = 15;
    const int num_elements_per_producer = 100000;

    vector<thread> producers;
    vector<thread> consumers;

    vector<int> producer_counts(num_producers, 0);
    vector<int> consumer_counts(num_consumers, 0);

    unordered_set<int> consumed_set[num_consumers];
    mutex consumed_set_mutex;

    atomic<int> producers_done(0);

    // Producer threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_producers; ++i) {
        producers.emplace_back([&stack, &producer_counts, i, num_elements_per_producer, &producers_done]() {
            srand(time(NULL));
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(RollDice()));
            for (int j = 0; j < num_elements_per_producer; ++j) {
                int value = i * num_elements_per_producer + j;
                stack.push(value);
                producer_counts[i]++;
            }
            producers_done++;
        });
    }

    // Consumer threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_consumers; ++i) {
        consumers.emplace_back([&stack, &consumer_counts, i, &consumed_set, &consumed_set_mutex, &producers_done, num_producers]() {
            LockFreeStack<int>::Node* value;
            while (producers_done != num_producers || !stack.empty()) {
                value = stack.pop();
                if (value) {
                    {
                        consumed_set[i].insert(value->data);
                    }
                    delete value;
                    consumer_counts[i]++;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for (auto& producer : producers) {
        producer.join();
    }
    for (auto& consumer : consumers) {
        consumer.join();
    }

    int total_produced = 0;
    for (int count : producer_counts) {
        total_produced += count;
    }

    int total_consumed = 0;
    for (int count : consumer_counts) {
        total_consumed += count;
    }

    if (total_produced != total_consumed) {
        cout << "total_produced != total_consumed\n";
    }

    if (!stack.empty()) {
        cout << "!stack.empty()\n";
    }

    unordered_set<int> total_consumed_set;
    for (int j = 0; j < num_consumers; j++) {
        for (int value : consumed_set[j]) {
            total_consumed_set.insert(value);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < total_produced; ++i) {
        if (total_consumed_set.find(i) == total_consumed_set.end()) {
            printf("consumed_set.find(%d) == consumed_set.end()\n", i);
        }
    }

    cout << "Test passed. Produced: " << total_produced
         << ", Consumed: " << total_consumed << endl;
}

int main() {
    test_lock_free_stack();
    return 0;
}


Problem
On modern Linux systems, the test passes successfully, and the results are as expected. However, on Windows and some older Linux systems , the test fails with issues like:

Mismatched producer and consumer counts.
Duplicated values in the consumed set lead to double deletion after the consumer pops the value, causing the program to crash
During the final check, values that were pushed onto the stack are missing when popped.

Questions：
Why is it that when using Boost and GCC 7 to cross-compile a static linked test program (to ensure the use of the same machine code), this test program works on a newer version of Linux (kernel version 4.19), but fails on an older version of Linux (kernel 4.4)?
Why does the test fail on Windows (7, 10, 11) regardless of whether I use Boost (version 1.73) or std (I’ve tried compiling with Clang and VS2022), whether on Win32 or x64?

Have you tested with -fsanitize=thread (Clang or GCC) to try to detect race conditions?  What compiler versions did your systems have?  If memory reordering is the problem, it's unlikely that kernel version is relevant, more likely compile-time reordering since you're testing on x86 and probably only need acq/rel ordering for anything which x86 does for free in hardware.  glibc version might matter for allocator behaviour, if you're freeing memory while a thread might still be accessing it.  Or maybe number of cores vs. number of threads you test with, if that leads to long sleeps.

It would be helpful to have a bullet list of systems you've tested on, with full details: was the bug reproducible on this system; OS and architecture; compiler version + options used to make the binary for that system; kernel and libc version; CPU model number, number of physical and logical cores, and microarchitecture name like Skylake or Zen 1, if you know it.  (CPU model is unlikely to be a factor; all x86-64 CPUs do StoreLoad reordering and store forwarding, but the HW memory model doesn't allow anything more.)

I haven't taken the time to fully look at the code, but ABA problems could be a possibility for your CAS loops, if a deleted node is reallocated by new so the address doesn't change but it should be treated as a different node.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem uses a lock-free stack as an example.

I think there's a fundamental race condition in your algorithm for pop.  Once you have loaded the value of head into q, there's nothing to prevent some other thread from popping that node and deleting it, and then accessing q->next is undefined behavior.
Consider the following interleaving of code.  Suppose for concreteness that head contains address 0xdeadbeef initially.  Thread A is a consumer which enters pop(), and thread B is another consumer.
Thread A                   Thread B (consumer)
q = head.load(memory_order_acquire);  // now q = 0xdeadbeef

                           value = stack.pop(); // value = 0xdeadbeef
                           if (value) {         // true
                               consumed_set[i].insert(value->data);
                               delete value;    // memory at 0xdeadbeef is now invalid
                           }

while (q && !head.compare_exchange_strong(q, q->next)) {}

In thread A, q still equals 0xdeadbeef which is not null.  But evaluating q->next attempts to access memory at 0xdeadbeef which is no longer valid, and the result is undefined behavior.
I don't know why it would be more likely to fail on some systems than others, but that's certainly not uncommon with undefined behavior.  For instance, some systems could be more prone to quickly reusing or overwriting deallocated memory.
Unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to fix this.  Lock-free data structures are very hard to get right.  You might need to do more research into proven correct algorithms.
Another tip is to use ThreadSanitizer on your test.  It detects a data race on delete which is likely this one (I didn't inspect the backtrace carefully).
